# converting an input from Textbox to Byte() in vb

Tags: vb.net, arrays, type-conversion, text-parsing

I am trying to do some RFID encoding in which I am going to type a 16 digits that are hexadecimal (0 --> F) into a Text-box in a form I have already created.  My issue is how do I convert that .Text format into something that is either convertible to a Byte() format or anything that is a sub-step to being converted to that format.

After a lot of research and a lot of repeated errors, I think whatever functions I am using are not treating each character as a single digit but the entire text as a value.  Therefore I tried parsing it into individual characters and it is still not allowing me to do that.

I have tried:

```
System.Convert.To___{anything, byte, integer, decimal,string}__(Next_TID.Text 
*or that same thing converted into a string* })


Dim text As New System.Text.StringBuilder(textinfo.Length \ 2)
for i As integer = 0 To textinfo.Length - 2 Step 2
     text.Apend(Chr(Convert.ToByte(textinfo.Substring(i,2), 16)))
Next
```

this continually gives me an error saying it could not find any recognizable digits, which I think means it views the entire thing as one large digit not individual ones.

I have not been coding in vb prior to two weeks ago, however with a lot of practice programs and research I don't know what I am doing wrong.  (sorry if the code samples did not show up right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work - give it a try:
The code builds both arrays of byte-values and of the binary number-strings (just for demonstration).

```
    Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim bytes As New List(Of Byte)
    Dim byteStrings As New List(Of String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 2 Step 2
        Dim hexDigit As Byte = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16)
        bytes.Add(hexDigit)
        byteStrings.Add(Convert.ToString(hexDigit, 2).PadLeft(8, "0"))
    Next

    Dim output As String = String.Join("-", byteStrings)
    MsgBox(output)
```

The byte values are just numbers, you can't get the binary strings from them without explicitly saying so. This is done with the `Convert.ToString(SomeNumericValue, 2)`.

Also, if you don't need the `-` spacers, you could simply do:

```
    Dim hexValue As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text, 16)
    MsgBox(Convert.ToString(hexValue, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast, That works.  I guess I was trying to view the text as an object not a text.